# How can I know whether the cost function has become the minimum or not?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement logistic regression without using ML related libraries, and having trouble optimizing the cost function.

I stored the history of cost function during the iteration.

At first, the cost function started with the value of 0.68, and it decreased to about 0.66, then increased since then, becoming even higher than the initial cost function.

Does this mean that I'm having some errors in my code?

Or, can 0.66 be the minimum of the cost function?

How can I know that the current cost function value is the minimum?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a flaw in the loss function / optimization step because there isn't much optimization from 0.68 to 0.66, whereas, ideally the loss should have decreased a lot more. Also, the optimization diverges rather than converging. To confirm if 0.66 indeed is a global minimum (highly unlikely) for your training loss, you need to cross-check the performance and the model network / loss function / optimization implementations with standard ML frameworks such as Tensorflow / PyTorch.

There are several ways to analyze the progress of your loss function with training and prevent your model from diverging after it has reached a local optimum, some of these methods are:

- Using [`Keras`](https://keras.io/callbacks/) `EarlyStopping`- a callback that allows you to specify the performance measure to monitor and the trigger to stop the training process if loss starts increasing (EarlyStopping [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-stop-training-deep-neural-networks-at-the-right-time-using-early-stopping/)). However, since you're **not using** Keras or any other ML library, you could just write a snippet of code that tracks the loss value trend of, say, the last 5 epochs and determines if the training needs to stop and saves the best model checkpoint.
- Visualization packages such as TensorBoard that allows for logging loss values as a summary (again **not possible** since you're not using ML visualization packages). So you could just use `matplotlib` for plotting the loss values over epochs which would help visualize the optimization trend especially if you're training for a lot of epochs.

Comment: Another good option for checking your result would be scikit learn libraries. 
Or you could create a very simple dataset, e.g. a few x,y points and do a linear regression with one variable. It should be easy to create a test case where you can set up an initial condition that is very far from the global minimum and then verfiy that your gradient descent solution is an improvement.